# Proper way to provide a default optional parameter

Tags: key-bindings, magit, keymap

I like doing PR reviews with Magit's diff, thus calling `magit-diff-visit-file` pretty often, providing a universal argument for the optional `other-window` parameter. To optimize the process instead of pressing `C-- <Ret>` i'd prefer just to use `<Ret>` key. What's the proper way to define such a behaviour?

I've seen people using `defalias` here and there, but not sure how's it going to work in terms of itself. I guess i can get away with defining a stub function and forward the call to `magit-diff-visit-file`, but i was thinking if there's a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`defalias` is useful when you want to give some existing function an alternative name. But you want to change what a certain key does, and that's a different problem.

You have to bind `"RET"` to some command in some keymap, a problem that can be broken down into two smaller problems: "what keymap?" and "what command?".

To find the appropriate keymap you can use `rgrep` in the directory containing the Magit source to search for `magit-diff-visit-file`.

Turns out you actually have to modify two keymaps `magit-file-section-map` and `magit-hunk-section-map` and that instead of `"RET"` you should use `[remap magit-visit-thing]`, though the former would work too.

```
(define-key magit-file-section-map [remap magit-visit-thing] '???)
(define-key magit-hunk-section-map [remap magit-visit-thing] '???)
```

Looking at the other matches and the code in close approximation suggests that no variation exists that behaves the way you want, but defining it is easy: copy `magit-diff-visit-file`, replace the body with a call to that function and adjust the name, signature and `interactive` form.

```
(defun magit-diff-visit-file-other-window (file)
  (interactive (list (--if-let (magit-file-at-point)
                         (expand-file-name it)
                       (user-error "No file at point"))))
  (magit-diff-visit-file file t))
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, thanks for your help Jonas!